# change the group of item in ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have `ICollectionView` looks like

```
public ICollectionView UsersCollectionView
{
    get
    {
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this);
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("SeriesName"));
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("CreationDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("DocumentTypeId", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        return view;
    }
}
```

I want to use drag & drop to change the item Series Name , and location on the list view any idea how to do that for example

```
--- ScienceFiction
------------> Book1 
------------> Book2
--- History 
------------> Book3 
------------> Book4
```

if  Idraged and droped book3 in ScienceFiction the output should be

```
--- ScienceFiction
------------> Book1 
------------> Book2
------------> Book3 
--- History 
------------> Book4
```

I use xaml code like this :

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="True">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbPersonList" Margin="19,17,162,25" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMH,

First modify the ListviewItem Style. It is the container that contains every line (datatemplate instanciation) of the listbox. It is a good place to manage Drag and Drop at the line level ( not a control of a line, there could be many in the DataTemplate). 
In Visual Studio, select the listbox, right click, Edit additional templates/Edit Generated Item Container(ItemContainerStyle)/Edit a copy

In the ListBoxItemStyle created, add those three declarations amongst the setters :

```
        <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.DragOver" Handler="ListBoxItemDragOver"/>
        <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.Drop" Handler="ListBoxItemDrop"/>
        <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBoxItemPreviewMouseMove"/>
```

Set the AllowDrop property to true on the ListBox :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listboxBooks" AllowDrop="True">
```

Then implement the handlers in the .xaml.cs code :

```
    #region DnD management

    private Book sourceBook;
    private void ListBoxItemPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            return;
        var listboxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (listboxItem == null)
            return;
        sourceBook = listboxItem.DataContext as Book;
        if (sourceBook == null)
            return;
        var data = new DataObject();
        data.SetData(sourceBook);
        // provide some data for DnD in other applications (Word, ...)
        data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, sourceBook.ToString());
        DragDropEffects effect = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listboxItem, data, DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
    private void ListBoxItemDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Book)))
            return;
        var listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
        if (listBoxItem == null)
            return;
        var targetBook = listBoxItem.DataContext as Book;
        if (targetBook != null)
        {
            viewModel.RecategorizeBook(sourceBook, targetBook.Category);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    private void ListBoxItemDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Effects);
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Book)))
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void GroupItemDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Book)))
            return;
        var groupItem = sender as GroupItem;
        if (groupItem == null)
            return;
        dynamic targetGroup = groupItem.DataContext;
        if (targetGroup != null)
        {
            // here I change the category of the book
            // and refresh the view of the collectionViewSource ( see link to project zipped further)
            viewModel.RecategorizeBook(sourceBook, targetGroup.Name as String);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    #endregion
```

Note that  I also implemented Drop management on the group header in the handlers. 
So the handler needs to be declared in the XAML groupstyle :

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="GroupItem.Drop" Handler="GroupItemDrop"/>
                <EventSetter Event="GroupItem.PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBoxItemPreviewMouseMove"/>
```

It works, here is full working code : http://1drv.ms/1FhBZwr

Wish you the best possible code

Comment: @AMH, isn't it the answer to you question ?

Comment: AMH, do you expect something more/different to award the bounty ?

Comment: To anyone around : would it be useful if I showed how to insert the dropped element at a given position in a group, not in the group, but at a random position ? That way the end user would be master of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately .net does not yet provide an "easy to use" implementation of drag'n'drop. You have to build a bunch of things on your own. The starting point will be a `Behavior` starting the drag and a `ContentControl` being the area onto which the user can drop things. Having those defined you can easily reuse this concept. In the following example the `StackPanel` can be "dragged" onto an invisible "area" surrounding the `TextBlock`. This way you are able to implement manually sorting your books (drop before/behind the book under the mouse pointer).

If you want to drop books onto your headers surround them with a `DropArea`. You could also implement both ways.

Your xaml will look like:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
[...]
<ListBox x:Name="lbPersonList" Margin="19,17,162,25" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <myOwn:DropArea>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </myOwn:DropArea>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <myOwn:DragBehavior/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The `DragBehavior` will look like:

```
public class DragBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    [...]
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObject_MouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.MouseDown += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave += AssociatedObject_MouseLeave;
        base.OnAttached();
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= AssociatedObject_MouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeave -= AssociatedObject_MouseLeave;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
    protected virtual void AssociatedObject_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (some condition of mouse button states or mouse moves)
        {
                DataObject data = new DataObject();
                data.SetData(typeof(anyKeyType), anyData);
                data.SetData(typeof(anyOtherKeyType), anyOtherData);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(fe, data, DragDropEffects.Move);                
        }
    }
```

The `DropArea` will look like:

```
public class DropArea : ContentControl
    [...]
    public DropArea()
    {
        DragEnter += AssociatedObjectDragEnter;
        DragLeave += AssociatedObjectDragLeave;
        DragOver += AssociatedObjectDragOver;
        IsTabStop = false;
        AllowDrop = true;
    }
    protected override void AssociatedObjectDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        object o = e.Data.GetData(typeof(anyKeyType));
        //handle dropped data
    }
```

Hope that may help you on your way. There may be any frameworks or libraries to adress that issue, but this way you can adress your own needs.